# My jQuery won't link to my HTML no matter what I try?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**EDIT: Thanks so much all, it was that damn API or whatever it is, I did download the files so I don't have to get it from the server, but I'll just use https instead.**

I have two questions.

1. Why does my code not work? I am trying to make a splash screen that is green and when clicked, fade to a red background.
2. What is this - `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` for exactly? I know it is to link the jQuery code but I don't know specifically.

My Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='anim.js'></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="splash">
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
#splash {

z-index: 100;
position: absolute;
background-color: #82a43a;
top: 0; 
right: 0; 
left: 0; 
bottom: 0;

}

body {

    background-color: red;

}
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#splash").click(function() {

$(this).fadeOut();

});
```

Comment: ***[working is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/ve6qLpz8/3/)***

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're running this website on your filesystem, not a server. Links starting with `//` are protocol relative, which means it tries to find that jQuery file from `file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js`, which doesn't exist.

Replace that line with this:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The native language is `javascript` in which we use to write function but `jquery` is a library created by javascript so if we need to use jquery we are restricted to use this library in our page to make DOM understand the jquery functions.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

And your functions are not working even after defining this library because whenever we use this library in our local system and calling the libraries from live server we need to make `http://` call to so you have to write it like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To load JQuery from Internet, you need to specify JQuery JS file link as follow:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

<kbd>***[here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/ve6qLpz8/5/)***</kbd>  is its Working demo using JQuery Js file as external Resources.

Answer (score 0):

please put your script inside document ready so it will work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#splash").click(function() {
     $(this).fadeOut();
    });
  });
```

write test or anything inside #splash div so you can trigger click perfectly.